# Casting Exceptions Using Generic Type Parameters: Right way to do it?

Tags: java, generics, exception, casting, annotations

Here is my sample class with embedded comments/questions.  Can you please advise the best way to handle this situation?

```
public abstract class AbstractThreadWithException<TException extends Exception>
extends Thread {

    private TException _exception;

    public TException getException() {
        return _exception;
    }

    // I don't like this annotation: SuppressWarnings.  Is there a work-around?
    // I noticed Google Guava code works very hard to avoid these annos.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            runWithException();
        }
        // By Java rules (at least what my compiler says):
        // I cannot catch type TException here.
        catch (Exception e) {
            // This cast requires the SuppressWarnings annotation above.
            _exception = (TException) e;
        }
    }

    public abstract void runWithException()
    throws TException;
}
```

I suppose it would be possible to pass a reference to `Class<? extends Exception>`, but that seems ugly.  Is there a more graceful solution?

Unfortunately, my brain is more hard-wired to C++ thinking than Java thinking, hence the confusion surrounding templates vs. generics.  I think this problem is related to type erasure, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the point is in using TException in the first place.  Why not just Exception and skip the generic stuff?  What you're doing has no effect, other than to make use of your class more difficult.

Comment: @HotLicks: Good point.  Reading your comment + tackline's response is making rethink this class.  Exactly why I posted my question to SO!

Comment: Make sure to read up on type erasure and what unchecked casts are. Don't use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before understanding those concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to recover runtime type information, so yes you'll need `Class.cast` or similar. As it stands your code can throw a `ClassCastException` **at the caller of `getException`** because you are catching and storing all `Exception`s.

You may find it better to remove the generics and have the caller use `instanceof` or similar.

Comment: @tackline: Before I read your answer, I had not (correctly) considered unchecked/runtime exceptions.  Now I can see it is so simple to "blow up" this code (via CCE) with a NPE thrown by `runWithException()`.  Cheers.